# Hadoop connector for marklogic deprecated from v10

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I read in the MarkLogic site that the MarkLogic Hadoop connector is deprecated and will be removed in future releases? Any reason behind such decision?
If we are considering to use hdfs for tier 3 storage, we should avoid? Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop Connector is different than HDFS file system support. If you're looking to use HDFS for Tier 3 storage, I believe you still can.

Comment: can we access the data from HDFS without MapReduce using MarkLogic? how can we handle the distributed file system using just marklogic?
Is HDFS the only recommended file system for tier 3 (excluding cloud)? 
HDFS has to be setup on a cheaper storage, correct?

Comment: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/disk-storage#id_27091